# Differential of a variable in Physics

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $(x^1,\ldots,x^n)$ a local chart en $M$. The differentials $dx^1,\ldots,dx^n$ are the dual basis asociated to $\partial/\partial x^1,\ldots,\partial/\partial x^n$.

From here, what is the justification (usually made in physics) for consider $dx^\mu$ as a small variation of the $x^\mu$ parameter?

Comment: I think you should just learn the new language of differential forms.

Comment: Dear @Jacky,  quite the contrary: if you understand  "the new language of differential forms" you must see that the idea that $dx^\mu$ is a small variation of the $x^\mu$ parameter makes absolutely no sense! How can a linear form on the tangent space of a manifold be "a small variation"  of a parameter? A non-zero linear form has as output arbitrarily large real numbers. To be more explicit it makes absolutely no sense to say that the map $x \mapsto 2x$ is a small variation of the $x$ parameter.